# views argument to header

Tags: views, search

I have a Search view that uses the Filter: Search terms.

I've tried using `<?php print arg(0); ?>` in the header, but that only returns the view url (search).

How do I get the value of the query key */search?keys=term* to be able to use it as a token in a Global: Text area in the Header?

My header title would be something like : Results for [search term]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_GET['keys'] should give you the term value.

Comment: also just found this module, for those with disdain for php code in views https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filter_query